# I keep getting "Unexpected end of JSON input"

Tags: node.js, json, api

```
app.get("/dashboard", function(req, res) {
  const country = "Singapore";

  // I used a constant in desperation

  const url =
    "https://api.covid19api.com/live/country/" + country;
  https.get(url, function(response) {
    response.on("data", function(data) {
      const caseData = JSON.parse(data);

      // Error stems from here

      res.render("cases", { caseData: caseData });
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: @AKX answer is correct. You can use a third party library to make life easier. I would've recommended https://github.com/request/request but it's deprecated. Look around and see if you can find any library you like.

Answer (score 2):

You're not waiting for the entire message before trying to parse it.

The `data` event is invoked for each chunk of data from the HTTP response. The response may not necessarily fit in a single chunk.

You'll have to wait for the `end` event before trying to parse the JSON... or preferably use a higher-level library such as `node-fetch` for a more comfortable promise-based API.